# Finally does not work in the exception handling of the dart?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, android-developer-api

[image]

Here the finally print not showing in the output, What should I have to do ,, If any mistake I am doing so please guide me.

I try to handle the exception and print the finally out put but it does not works.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to execute wrong file that's why you are not able to see your desire output . Your code is in `finallywork.dart` file and you are executing `trycatch.dart` file .

Answer (score 0):

You are doing 2 mistakes,

1. You are editing the fine named `finallywork.dart`
2. You are running the file named `trycatch.dart`

Try running the command

```
dart finallywork.dart
```

[image]